# SSIS Script Task Error after upgrading package form 2008 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've got an SSIS package that has been upgraded to SQL Server 2012 and I am getting a runtime error when it tries to run a simple Script task.

The runtime error gives very little information.

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

It does seem that this is happening right when it tries to execute the script because I set a breakpoint right where it enters main() and it doesn't even get there.  Almost as if it can't find the compiled script or something.

Here is the script code: which is pretty simple.

```
/*
   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
   Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
   The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.
*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;



namespace ST_645b1fbdfe504c9482df626a189b6659.csproj
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        /*
        The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
        To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
        and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.

        To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value;
        To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, null);
        To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, true);

        To use the connections collection use something like the following:
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

        Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.

        To open Help, press F1.
    */

        public void Main()
        {
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_TripKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_ActionKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_ServiceKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_ZoneKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_YardKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_MTTapDateKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_MTTapTimeKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_StopKeyEndDateNull1");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_NoPlatformKey2");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_RouteID0");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_PlatformKey1");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_NoPlatformKey3");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_NoPlatformKey1");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_NoPlatformKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_InstitutionKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_ProductKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_CardKey");
            WriteError("Error_FactEFCTaps_StageTaps_VehicleKeyTraxFR");


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        public void WriteError(string variable)
        {
            //serialize to xml
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables[variable].Value);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            string xml = ds.GetXml();

            if (xml != "<NewDataSet />")
            {
                //write to db
                string ErrSource = Dts.Variables[variable].Name;
                string BatchID = Dts.Variables["BatchID"].Value.ToString();
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
                cn = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DW01_ADO"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert dbo.EFC_ErrorRows_XML(ErrorSource,RowData,BatchID) values(@ErrorSource, @XML,@BatchID)", cn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ErrorSource", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ErrSource;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@XML", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xml;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BatchID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = BatchID;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is it doesn't like the namespace for some reason.  Try pasting the script into a new script task generated after the conversion to 2012 and see how that goes.

Comment: Tried that.  Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and figured out that SSIS was looking for a DLL I was referencing within the script task and not finding it.  For some reason it was only looking in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn folder.

Comment: Where SHOULD it be looking? And what was the DLL?

Comment: Isn't there a reference path within the script task properties?